# Copying a char array to another const char array during declaration

Tags: c, arrays, string, generic-programming

What I am trying to do is take a string pointed to by `argv[1]` and copy it into another array, but I want this new array to be const.

Is there a way to declare the array as const and initialize it with the contents of `argv[1]` on the same line?

The problem I'm having is that I can't declare it as `const` and then on the next line copy the string over using `strcpy` or some such function. That's invalid.

What's the best course of action?

Comment: What about a pointer to const char, and just point it at `argv[1]`?  Unless you plan to modify argv[1] later...

Comment: That's actually an excellent idea. That might be the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *argument = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", argument);

    return 0;
}
```

leveraging the fact that argument[0] is substantially the same of *argument.
But beware!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *argument = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", argument);

    argument[2] = 'z';    //ERROR
    printf("%s\n", argument);

    return 0;
}
```

this above causes an error as expected. But...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *argument = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", argument);

    argv[1][2] = 'z';     //same memory location but no errors
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", argument);

    return 0;
}
```

causes no error .... in fact in the last printf you can see that your string has been edited.

Comment: This all makes total sense, that's the correct solution. Thank you for your answer, I'm always amazed at how helpful this place is.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you don't want to modify it (it being a const and all), you don't even need to copy it somewhere:

(Basic code lacking sanity checks such as correct argument count and argument lenght)

```
const char *myPointer = NULL;
myPointer = argv[1];
```

Now myPointer is pointing to `argv[1]`, your first argument that the program was launched with.

So if you launch your program like `myfolder/myexe.exe myArg` your `myPointer` will point to a char array with these contents `{'m','y','A','r','g','\0'}`